# Finding closely located points in a large, sparse, noisy volume

Tags: java, distance

Sorry in advance for the text wall--it's been a while since I've done programming and there's probably better terminology for what I mean to say.  Searched everything I could think of and didn't find any related questions on the site, but maybe with better terms we could find one, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**I'm trying to improve performance in finding groups of objects separated by no more than a set [taxicab/Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).**  So, say my distance is 'x', point 'a' is x units from point 'b', point 'b' is x units from 'c', and point 'c' is x+3 units from point 'a';  I should identify a, b, and c as a group, as well as any object within x units of any of them (and so on).

I have identified several simple algorithms for finding these groups but I think the performance can be better.  Clustering algorithms seem like they should be relevant here, but I haven't been able to find an algorithm which suits my problem precisely.  I'm also not sure I'm storing the data as effectively as I could be--for now I am just working with static data so I can copy it into whatever form I need before I begin; however in the future I would like to have an implementation that can efficiently handle points being added and removed.  Here are the details:

- I start with two unordered ArrayLists of objects which have among their many properties a unique triplet of integer coordinates (x,y,z).
- The objects are scattered sparsely over a very large volume (say, 500 million cubic units) and my set distance is comparatively small (<15 units)
- I don't need to find groups of size 1, so there is a lot of "noise".  Groups of more than three are quite rare in my data.
- More than 90% of the time nearby objects are added to the ArrayLists at similar times, so I would like to take advantage of that fact if I can.
- Another helpful fact is that one dimension (y) has about 1/10 the range of the other two, so two-dimensional algorithms might be a faster way to start, with two-dimensional groups split up later if necessary.
- Once I find these groups I need access to each object in the group for function calls, so I need to identify the object, not just the coordinate.

**How can I improve over the performance of just looping through the ArrayLists twice with offset grids and then re-analysing the groups I create?**  My language is Java, but algorithms are more important than specific types and libraries (though I'll take those too!).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to implement special case of a [Range search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_search). Perhaps storing your data in a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) will be useful. At the very least you should be able to easily extract the points located in a hyper cube surrounding one of the points you are searching around. Then you can check if their distance matches the requirement.

Also see: "[Fixed-Radius Near Neighbors and Geometric Basics](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~pless/546/lectures/Lecture2.pdf)" for some solutions.

Comment: It seems like a range search would be if I was looking for points within a specific designated area (unless I run a range search on the area around every point looking for other points).  On the other hand, the "Fixed-radius near neighbors" problem looks almost exactly like what I need!  The optimal solution in the reporting case involves "bucketing", which sounds very similar to my grids.  The article you linked points out that I only need to bucket once, and then search the adjacent buckets once I find an _occupied_ bucket, which helps a lot with my sparse data.  I'll try it and report back!